# Round-robin tournament

Tags: combinatorics

In a round-robin tournament, each player plays every other player exactly once, where there are a total of $n$ players. Then,

$(i)$ What is the sum of wins and losses for each player?

$(ii)$ If there is a player who is undefeated, then how many wins does the player have?

$(iii)$ If there is no player who is undefeated, then what is the most wins of a player?

Concerning about these sub-parts, I think answer for $(i)$ would be $n(n-1)$, but have no idea on how to solve $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ (possibly I got wrong for them)

Comment: Your answer for $i$ is not correct.  How many games does each player play?

Comment: One player plays how many games? So what would be (ii)?

Comment: @cosmo5 I think my answers for $(i), (ii), (iii)$ would be $2n$, $n-1$, and $n-2$, respectively. Are they correct, or where did I make mistakes?

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry for wrong typo in $(i)$. I edited the post.

Comment: @AnarRzayev, ($i$) is incorrect, rest correct.

Comment: I edited the post again. Could you check whether I got correct answer for part $(i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

Sum of wins and losses = Total number of games played

Comment: Is it $n(n-1)$?

Comment: I considered the case when $n = 3, 4$ and observed that answer equals $n(n-1)$

Comment: Yes, for all $n$ players. For one player it's only $n-1$.

Comment: It is alike 2 * (n choose 2), right?

Comment: That's correct! You got it.